# Exception: multiple definitions for function in body

Tags: scheme, lisp, chez-scheme

I have a simple program:

```
(import (rnrs))
(define (abs x)
    (cond ((> x 0) x)
           ((= x 0) 0)
           ((< x 0) (- x))
           ))
(define (square x)
    (* x x))
(define (sum-sq x y)
    (+ (square x) (square y)))
(display
    (sum-sq (read) 3))
```

When I run it, I have an exception; what did I do wrong?

> /home# scheme-script /home/scheme/main.ss
> Exception: multiple definitions for abs in body (top-level-program
> #<annotation /home/scheme/main.ss[0:15] (import (...))> #<annotation /home/scheme/main.ss)[17:122] (define (...) (...))> #<annotation
> /home/scheme/main.ss[124:156] (define (...) (...))> #<annotation
> /home/scheme/main.ss[158:210] (define (...) (...))> #<annotation
> /home/scheme/main.ss[212:244] (display (...))> near line 1, char 1 of
> /home/scheme/main.ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is illegal to redefine a variable in a top-level program in R6RS Scheme. OP has executed the script using `scheme-script`; in Chez Scheme `scheme-script` is equivalent to `scheme --program`, which treats the file as a top-level program. It is fine to redefine things in the REPL when you are experimenting with definitions, unless you wrap that code in a `top-level-program` form.

`scheme --script` treats the file as a shell script, while `scheme-script` (i.e., `scheme --program`) treats it as a top-level program. To demonstrate that OP's problem is a result of the file being treated as a top-level program, run it using `scheme --script`, then wrap the posted code in a `(top-level-program ...)` form and try running again with `scheme --script`. The first attempt will execute successfully, and the second will again raise an exception.

One solution to OP's problem is to use `scheme --script` instead of `scheme-script` (or `scheme --program`). Of course, one could simply use the built-in `abs` procedure, or rename the new procedure as, e.g., `my-abs`.

But, sometimes you really do want to use an identifier that has previously been claimed by some library that you need to import. For that situation there is `except`. Here is a version of OP's code using `except` in the `import` form:

```
(import (except (rnrs) abs))

(define (abs x)
  (if (< x 0) (- x) x))

(define (my-abs x)
  (<))
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (sum-sq x y)
  (+ (square x) (square y)))

(display "Enter a number: ")
(let ((x (read)))
  (display x) (display "^2 + 3^2 = ") (display (sum-sq x 3)) (newline))

(display "Enter a number: ")
(let ((x (read)))
  (display "|") (display x) (display "| = ") (display (abs x)) (newline))

;;; Easier with Chez Scheme `format`, which can be made available by
;;; changing the `import` form at the top to:
;;;
;;;  (import (except (chezscheme) abs))

;; (display "Enter a number: ")
;; (let ((x (read)))
;;   (format #t "~A^2 + 3^2 = ~A~%" x (sum-sq x 3)))

;; (display "Enter a number: ")
;; (let ((x (read)))
;;   (format #t "|~A| = ~A~%" x (abs x)))
```

This program imports all identifiers which are exported from the `rnrs` library, except for `abs`. The top-level program is then free to define an `abs` identifier.

```
$ scheme-script top-level.ss 
Enter a number: 4
4^2 + 3^2 = 25
Enter a number: -42
|-42| = 42
```

### What the Standard Says

A top-level program is like a library, except that it cannot contain `export` forms. From [R6RS 7.1. Library form](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-10.html#node_sec_7.1):

> ... no identifier can be imported multiple times, defined multiple times, or both defined and imported.

The specification continues:

> The expressions of variable definitions are evaluated from
> left to right, as if in an implicit **letrec***....

But, by [11.4.6. Binding constructs](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.6), in a `letrec*` form:

> (**letrec*** <bindings> <body>)‌‌ syntax
>
> Syntax: <Bindings> must have the form
>
> ((<variable1> <init1>) ...),
>
> where each <init> is an expression, and <body> is as described in
> section 11.3. ***Any variable must not appear more than once in the
> <variable>s***.

So an identifier can't be imported multiple times, both imported and defined, or defined and redefined in a library or top-level program. The OP code violates this by both importing a definition for an identifier, and redefining that identifier within the top-level program.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite explicit: you're redefining `abs`, which is a built-in procedure. Depending on the Scheme interpreter in use, this can be a problem - in particular, you can't redefine a procedure in Chez Scheme. Simply delete `abs`, it's already provided by the language.